# Squash feature branch commit after merging from master

Tags: git, version-control, merge, rebase, pull-request

I am trying to squash commits in a branch to that when it is finally merged to master (after pull request if aproved) the commit history looks clean.Hence before raising the pull request I do a

```
git rebase -i
```

and rewrite the history.

However while developing the feature in its branch I have to merge the content of the master onto the branch because master usually moves ahead due to other feature branches being merged.

I see ones I merged master to feature branch I can not squash he commits any more using interactive rebase. It leads to unusual diff during pull requests i.e. changes which came as part of merges from master.

What is the best way to squash the commits in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to squash commits in a branch to that when it is finally merged to master (after pull request if aproved) the commit history looks clean

You can use `soft reset` to squash your branch (say, `feature`) commits. Say you have 5 commits in `feature` branch. Now you need 5 commits = 1 new commit.

```
$ git checkout feature
$ git log              # see how many commits do you need to squash

$ git reset --soft HEAD~4  # note: if you have N commits then HEAD~{N-1}
Or, git reset --soft <first-commit> # reset to first commit of your branch

$ git add .               # add the files  
$ git commit --amend -m 'Squash all commits' # squash all the commits

$ git push -f origin feature  # force(-f) push to remote since git history is changed
```

Now, Pull master branch changes.

```
$ git pull origin master
```

Create a Pull request now using GitHub GUI (browser).

Comment: Does this not require that your local commits be the last 4? If you're periodically merging with master, that's not likely to be the case.

Comment: Is `--amend` necessary? What does it do here?

Comment: `--amend` is merging current local changes with previous commit (first-commit). Actually, git takes: last commit + current local changes = generate a brand new commit (commit hash/ref is changed)! @BoltzmannBrain

Answer (score 33):

If you just want to sqaush everything, then you have a way simpler way to do that that does not rely on using interactive rebasing. You can just do a soft reset to your master branch and then commit those changes:

```
git reset --soft master
git commit -m 'All changes from my branch squashed'
```

This basically resets the branch pointer to the `master` branch, without changing any of the content in your working directory. So the result is that you have all those changes in your index which you can commit then at once.

Comment: This answer is great. I used to look at the git log and find the commit hash of the last thing I didn't want included in my squash, then do a soft reset to that commit. This solution gets exactly what I want even if you've merged other branches into yours and the git log is messy.  My colleague used to do the interactive rebase and after I told him about this method, he's going to switch as well. Works great. Thanks!

Comment: Does this also roll the most recent changes in master into your squash?  i.e. if my branch is "my_commit1 -> my_commit2", and a merge with master would result in "my_commit1 -> your_commit -> my_commit2", does this result in "all_three_commits_in_one" or "your_commit -> all_of_my_commits"?

Comment: @Him This solution does not take into account any changes on master that haven’t been merged into your branch. After soft resetting to master, you will have the same content in your working directory that you had before and you will commit the delta to the master. Basically, you commit everything you see with `git diff master`. If there has been a new commit on master that you don’t want to revert, you should temporarily merge those changes into your branch first and then do the soft reset.

Answer (score 8):

If you want the feature branch is on the top of master branch, so that your pull request contains changes from other feature branches merged. You can use below commands:

```
git checkout feature
git pull origin master --rebase
```

This will rebase feature branch on the top of master branch after fetching from origin master.